# Declare error handler not valid in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling, syntax-error

I'm trying to write my first stored procedure that uses an error handler, but It doesn't seem to accept my syntax. Here's what I'm using:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE min_list_valid (OUT pass CHAR
                                ,OUT errs VARCHAR(50)
                                ,IN `@list_id` INT
                                ,IN `@min_input` INT)
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `errors_table`;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `errors_table`(error VARCHAR(30))ENGINE=MEMORY;
    END;

    BEGIN
        DECLARE error_holder VARCHAR(30);
        DECLARE error_checker VARCHAR(30);
        SET error_checker = 0;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE, SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'The user input is less than the minimum for this list' INTO error_holder;
            SELECT error_holder INTO `errors_table`;
            SET error_checker = 1;
        END;

        SELECT      IF(MAX(CAST(`peg_num` AS UNSIGNED))<`@min_input`,'pass',NULL) AS `key`
        FROM        `game_lists`
        WHERE       `list_id` = `@list_id`
        INTO        pass;

        IF error_checker <> 0 THEN
            SELECT * FROM `errors_table`
        END IF;
    END;
END; //
```

It gives me back the error message:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE, SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN ' at line 16`

But that's strange, it's telling me the declare is wrong but the line in error is line 16 (the one with `SET error_checker = 0`). I believe I'm following the correct syntax so... what's wrong?

What this stored proc just does is select some maximum value from a list, and everything else is just me trying to create an error handler and an error table to store the generated errors. I wanted to try a simple functionality first with the "full blown" error handling so there's not too many debug points.

My MySQL version is 5.6.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your corrected procedure should look like below. Few mistakes as pointed below

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE min_list_valid (OUT pass CHAR
                                ,OUT errs VARCHAR(50)
                                ,IN `@list_id` INT
                                ,IN `@min_input` INT)
BEGIN
        DECLARE error_holder VARCHAR(30); <--Move this declare statement above here
        DECLARE error_checker VARCHAR(30);
        SET error_checker = 0;
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `errors_table`;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `errors_table`(`error` VARCHAR(30))ENGINE=MEMORY; 

END;

BEGIN <-- after begin you should declare only the error handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000', SQLEXCEPTION
                                            <-- Provide a valid SQL State                                
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'The user input is less than the minimum for this list' INTO error_holder;
        INSERT INTO `errors_table`(`error`) SELECT error_holder;
        SET error_checker = 1;
    END;

    SELECT      CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(`peg_num` AS UNSIGNED)) < @min_input THEN 'pass'
                ELSE NULL END AS `key`
    FROM        `game_lists`
    WHERE       `list_id` = `@list_id`
    INTO        pass;

    IF error_checker <> 0 THEN
        SELECT * FROM `errors_table`;
    END IF;
END;
END; //
```

Comment: Thanks! I see, of course, declaring should always be at the top. I'm running this now though and it asks me to declare the "errors_table" variable, even though I'm creating a temporary table. How would I go about declaring this?

Comment: @markovchain, there was few more mistakes made by you. Check edit. it will be fine now.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! It's great I now have a base SP to refer to and analyze. Thanks again! :)